# How to prevent unknown addresses which are accessed from my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, security

I developed a website using wordpress. In the log file (which shows the ip addresses and the pages which have been accessed) I got some unknown addresses which have been accessed from my site although they are not actually exist.
These addresses have been accessed from many parts of the world. Some example addresses are:

xxx/c3e/bfv-fake-gps-without-allow-mock-locations
xxx/c3e/bfv-software-to-monitor-computer-activity-remotely-free 
xxx//rl8/bbx/7-hack-app-that-allow-you-to-view-wifes-or-girlfriends-facebook-secretly.html 
xxx/c3e/bfv-keylogger-for-windows-phone

here xxx represents my actual web address.
Do you have any idea about these address, their purpose and how to prevent these?

Comment: You cannot prevent people from sending requests to your server.

Comment: Are they just requests? or some attackers trying to access my site? How they use similar urls from different parts of the world?

Comment: There is no real difference between a request and an attacker.

Comment: How can I secure my website from these?

Comment: Just make sure there are no vulnerabilities that the requests can exploit.

Comment: If these links loads some content then your website is under attack by malware and it's better to hire some professional for cleaning malware and fixing loopholes. And if it doesn't show any content OR shows 404 (Not Found) page then there's nothing much to worry about. But you should keep eye on that.